# How to update libpq version in netbeans?

Tags: php, postgresql, netbeans

I want to use PHP to connect with PostgreSQL in netbeans. But when i run my application it will show me `pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`. Does anyone know how can i update libpq in netbeans? Or anyways to get rid of this problem?

Comment: [There are several questions here on the error you are getting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D+%22scram+authentication+requires+version+10%22). If any of the proposed solutions are relevant, but did not work for you, then update your question accordingly.

Comment: How did you install netbeans?